# Non-breaking space next to span tag doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm using `&nbsp;` to prevent the last two words of a sentence from separating into separate lines

```
prevent last two words from&nbsp;separating
```

But when I put `&nbsp;` after a span tag, it doesn't work.

```
prevent last two words <span>from</span>&nbsp;
separating
```

I'm using the span tag for styling and would like to prevent adding another tag for white-space: nowrap

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of "&nbsp;" try "&#160;" and see if it resolves your issue
```

Comment: Thanks but no, this does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My span element is using a Pseudo-class which was causing this behavior. Once I removed it, `&nbsp;` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the word “separating” in the same line as (and immediately next to) `&nbsp;`.

Right know you have:

```
prevent last two words <span>from</span>&nbsp;
separating
```

when it should be:

```
prevent last two words <span>from</span>&nbsp;separating
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right but the way I formatted the example was for presentation purposes only. I realized that I was using a pseudo class on the span tag which was causing the issue.